# jasig cas too many redirects issue

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, cas, jasig, spring-security-cas

I'm trying to secure a spring-boot web application using spring security and spring-security-cas (SSO with Jasig CAS).

I'm facing a too many redirects error when trying to access a protected resources. The project is available [here](https://github.com/ikane/microservices-demo-security-cas.git)

Do you see any error in my configuration?

Thanks in advance

[redirect loop error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZNgE.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found out the error:

> In SpringSecurity 4.x, CasAuthenticationFilter's defaultFilterProcessesUrl path is changed. So Change '/j_spring_cas_security_check' to '/login/cas' in Configuration.

So in my application.properties file, i had to change

```
app.service.security=http://localhost:7777/j_spring_cas_security_check
```

to

```
app.service.security=http://localhost:7777/login/cas
```

So the ServiceProperties Bean would become

```
   @Bean
    public ServiceProperties serviceProperties() {
        ServiceProperties serviceProperties = new ServiceProperties();
        serviceProperties.setService("http://localhost:7777/login/cas");
        serviceProperties.setSendRenew(false);
        return serviceProperties;
    }
```

Hope it'll help someone else!

Comment: Are you running cas-server locally on port 7777?  Or does your application implement something at /login/cas?  I'm really struggling to get my app working with CAS.